# How to provide ViewModel that has constructor with parameters to XAML page BindingContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms

Provide `BindingContext` of the ViewModel to XAML page have benefits of IntelliSense. However, this syntax only works if the `ViewModel` has an empty contractor eg: MainPageViewModel()

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:MainPageViewModel />
      </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

If MainPageViewModel doesn't have empty constructor but only have parameters constructor eg: MainPageViewModel(param1, param2), then the above XAML syntax will throw compile error. How would I do this in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at [WeeklyXamarin.Mobile Repo](https://github.com/weeklyxamarin/WeeklyXamarin.mobile). I found that this can be implemented nicely with the following:

- Create a `PageBase` as follow:

public class PageBase : ContentPage { }

```
public class PageBase<TViewModel> : PageBase
{
    public TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public PageBase()
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModel = Container.Instance.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Then the ViewModel in XAML can be passed in with `x:TypeArguments` like:

```
<views:PageBase
x:Class="WeeklyXamarin.Mobile.Views.AboutPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WeeklyXamarin.Core.ViewModels;assembly=WeeklyXamarin.Core"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WeeklyXamarin.Mobile.Views"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WeeklyXamarin.Core.ViewModels;assembly=WeeklyXamarin.Core"
Title="{Binding Title}"
x:TypeArguments="viewmodels:AboutViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

`AboutViewModel` has a parameter in the contractor and work nicely with the app

```
 public AboutViewModel(INavigationService navigation, IDataStore dataStore) : base(navigation)
```

Credit: Mr Kym Phillpotts for his code at WeeklyXamarin repo

Answer (score 2):

You could have a default constructor for your view model that would just serve IntelliSense purposes and then use the view model constructor with parameters in the page's constructor. That would give you the IntelliSense while being able to call the view models parameterized constructor. Something like this:

View model

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    
    //intellisense only constructor
    public SomeViewModel(){
        SomeValue = "test";
    }

    //real constructor
    public SomeViewModel(string someValue){
        SomeValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

Page XAML

```
<Window.BindingContext>
    <local:SomeViewModel />
</Window.BindingContext>
```

Page constructor

```
public SomePage()
{
    this.BindingContext = new SomeViewModel("real value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could not do that in xaml. There is no such syntax in Xamarin.forms. The default usage is the constructor with no parameters. Make a simple example for your reference.

ViewModel:

```
 public class viewModels
{
    public string text1 { get; set; }

    public viewModels()
    {
        text1 = "text1";

    }
}
```

BindingContext in xaml:

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding text1}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label.BindingContext>
                <local:viewModels />
            </Label.BindingContext>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
```